# O que faz o asterisco junto de uma letra no argumento do vetor, o porque disso no código?

Tags: python-3.x

Eae galera, blz?, Estou estudando sobre vetores com a biblioteca pygame do python e não entendo o porque de um asterisco junto da letra A no vetor definido na variável position lá embaixo no código. Alguém consegue me explicar qual o comportamento disso no código?

```
import pygame
import math

class Vector2():

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):

        return "(%s, %s)" %(self.x, self.y)

    def from_points(P1, P2):

        return Vector2 ( P2[0] - P1[0], P2[1] - P1[1] )

    def get_magnitude(self):

        return math.sqrt( self.x**2 + self.y**2 )

    def normalize(self):

        magnitude = self.get_magnitude()
        self.x /= magnitude
        self.y /= magnitude 


    def __add__(self, rhs): # rhs quer dizer Right Hand Side (Lado Direito)

        return Vector2(self.x + rhs.x , self.y + rhs.y)

    def __mul__(self, scalar):

        return Vector2(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar)

    def __truediv__(self, scalar):

        return Vector2(self.x / scalar, self.y / scalar)



A = (10.0, 20.0)
B = (30.0, 35.0)
AB = Vector2.from_points(A, B)
step = AB * .1
position = Vector2(*A) # esse asterisco junto a letra A que não entendi 
for n in range(10):
    position += step
    print(position)
```

Comment: Em resumo ele faz a desconstrução de tupla definindo cada valor de `A` como um parâmetro de `Vector2`. Seria o equivalente a fazer `Vector2(A[0], A[1])` nesse caso.

Comment: Valew Woss, agora o código faz sentido pra mim. Não sou muito experiente com python, mas nunca tinha visto isso em python.